# Matching integral answer to one of the options through manipulation.

Tags: integration

The question I'm solving goes like this. Its a question from a 12th grade math workbook -

> if $ I = \int {e^x \over e^{4x} + e^{2x} + 1} dx$ and $ J = \int {e^{-x} \over e^{-4x} + e^{-2x} + 1} dx$. Then $J-I = $?

It's a multiple choice question and the solution leads to the option — $$\frac{1}{2}\log\left|\frac{e^{2x}-e^x+1}{e^{2x} + e^x + 1}\right| + c$$[See solved textbook solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwW81.png)

I tried this question with a separate method of solving the integrals differently but the answer is coming with an extra term.

[See my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuTBB.png)

$$ -{1 \over \sqrt{3}} \arctan\left({e^{2x} -1 \over \sqrt 3 t}\right) +  \frac{1}{2}\log\left|\frac{e^{2x}-e^x+1}{e^{2x} + e^x + 1}\right| + c$$

I also differentiated the two terms that are coming and the answer is right just not matching the given options. Is there a way to come to the answer in the options through manipulation?

Comment: You still have a t in your answer. Did you perhaps forget to substitute back in for x? It might cause the extra term to cancel

Comment: You may not two different substitutions for the same integral simultaneously

Comment: The two integrals you have written in your question are different from the ones in your provided link btw

Comment: $t$ stands for two different things in the $J-I$ term simultaneously: both $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Thanks. That was it. I used different substitutions and put them back in as the same.

Comment: @Nuke_Gunray Oh I just saw, I was having a hard time with the LaTeX, so I must’ve written it incorrectly. Fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in the printed question in your book $$I=\int \frac{e^x dx}{e^{4x}+e^{2x}+1}, \quad J=\int \frac{e^{-x} dx}{e^{-4x}+e^{-2x}+1}=\int \frac{e^{3x} dx}{e^{4x}+e^{2x}+1}$$

Now write $$J-I= \int \frac{e^{3x}-e^{x}}{e^{4x}+e^{2x}+1}dx$$
as a single integral and proceed by taking $e^x=t$.

If you put $e^x=t$ in $I$ and  $e^{-x}=t$ in $J$ it is inconsistent, obviously.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
J-I &=\int \frac{e^{3 x}-e^{x}}{e^{4 x}+e^{2 x}+1} d x \\
&=\int \frac{y^{2}-1}{y^{4}+y^{2}+1} d y, \quad \text { whac } y=e^{x} \\
&=\int \frac{1-\frac{1}{y^{2}}}{y^{2}+\frac{1}{y^{2}}+1} d y \\
&=\int \frac{d\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right)}{\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right)^{2}-1} \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{y+\frac{1}{y}-1}{y+\frac{1}{y}+1}\right|+C \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{e^{2 x}-e^{x}+1}{e^{2 x}+e^{x}+1}\right|+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Wish it helps!